# Extracting named groups and non_named groups with fuzzy regex

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search

I'm searching for a way to apply a regex to a texts and extract its values in the form of a dictionary.
The Groups in the regexes can be named, non-named or mixed.
Ideally, I would use fuzzy matching (Allow some errors in the text).

**Text example:** `Name: foo BaR; Age: 42`
**Regex Example:** `Name: (?<name>[a-z]+) (?<lastname>[A-Z]+); Age: (\d+)'`
**Expected Output:** `{name: foo, lastname: BaR, gr0: 42}`

With the question, I also post my answer below
If there is a better way, I would be happy to take it ;)

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I use so far.

- 1st: modify the regex such that every group is a named-group
- 2nd: add an error possibility to the regex (with `{e<=3}`)
- 3rd: use `regex.search(...).capturedict()` to extract dict of named-groups

```py
text="Name: foo BaR; Age: 42"
pattern = r'Name: (?<name>[a-z]+) (?<lastname>[A-Z]+); Age: (\d+)'

def name_groups_in_regex(pattern):
    '''Make sure that all the groups in the regex are named-groups
    Replace a non-named-group by "gr<idx>"
    '''
    # Pattern to get non-named group
    get_parenthesis_pattern = r"(?<!\\)\((?!\?)"

    # Count matches
    n_parenthesis = len(re.findall(get_parenthesis_pattern, pattern))
    
    # substitute non-named group with named group
    pattern = re.sub(get_parenthesis_pattern, "(?<gr%d>", pattern)
    pattern = pattern % tuple(i for i in range(n_parenthesis))

    return pattern

# Name the groups in the regex
pattern = name_groups_in_regex(pattern)

# Perform fuzzy matching with an overall maximum of 3 'errors'
fuzzy_pattern = f'({pattern}){{e<=3}}'
regex.search(fuzzy_pattern, text, regex.BESTMATCH).capturesdict()
```

**Output**: `{'name': ['foo'], 'lastname': ['BaR'], 'gr0': ['42']}`

Comment: where is this fuzzy matching `{e<=3}` documented

Comment: You can look at the section __Approximate “fuzzy” matching__ of https://pypi.org/project/regex/
(Note that I'm using ```regex``` and not ```re```)